# Nested loop stopping after first iteration in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, internationalization

I want to iterate over a json with the following format:

```
{
 results: {
   0: {
       "message": "This is a message!"
       "Recipients": {
          0: {
              "name": "I'm a recipient"
               }
          1: {
              "name": "I'm another recipient"
             }
           }
         }
       1: {
            "message": "This is another message"
             "recipients" : {
             0: {

            ...
       ...
   ...
  }
```

I iterate throught it with something like the follow:

```
results.forEach(result, index) => {
           resultsArray.push(
              [t("inbox.message")]: result?.message
              )
           if (!isEmpty(result?.recipients)
               result.recipients.forEach((recipient) => {
                 resultsArray[index][t("inbox.recipient")] = recipient.name
                 });
               } ...
```

However, I end up getting an array like the following:

```
{
    "(translated message_title)": "This is a message",
    "(translated recipient_name)": "This is a recipient"
}
```

While what I do want is something like:

```
{
    "(translated message_title)": "This is a message",
    "(translated recipient_name)": "This is a recipient"
    "(translated recipient_name)": "This is another recipient"

}
```

Hope I've been clear: I obviously simplified the model to be brief, but it's actually pretty much the same as this, only that it used different and more attributes.

I suspect the problem is something aroud i18n, but I'm really not sure about the cause.

Thanks

Comment: Your current code should not work. You don't have any arrays anywhere, so `forEach` should throw. You'll need to convert the object into an array of values or array of entries first somehow.

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry, didn't clarify for celerity. It indeeds works, the component gets passed an array when called and returns a reduced array that is then transformed into an excel file.

Comment: While simplifying your model for the question, you probably did not mention some conversions, or changed arrays into objects, which is confusing for readers.

Answer (score 0):

An object cannot have the same key multiple times. So in your nested loop, when you do:

```
resultsArray[index][t("inbox.recipient")] = recipient.name
```

...you *overwrite* the value for key `t("inbox.recipient")` with the last `recipient.name`.

So what you get should be:

```
[{
  "(translated message_title)": "This is a message!",
  "(translated recipient_name)": "I'm another recipient" // Name of last recipient for this message
}]
```

If you want an *array* of all recipients' name, you could do something like that instead:

```
resultsArray[index][t("inbox.recipient")] =
  result?.recipients.map(recipient => recipient.name)
```

...which should give you:

```
[{
  "(translated message_title)": "This is a message!",
  "(translated recipient_name)": [
    // Array with all recipients' name
    "I'm a recipient",
    "I'm another recipient"
  ]
}]
```